# Sending alert emails from a bunch of servers to G Suite

Tags: email, sendmail, spf, g-suite, alerting

We have a always changing infrastructure (DigitalOcean droplets and AWS EC2 instances that are created and deleted). We use Ansible to bootstrap VMs and to install netdata on each VM. The goal is to have emails coming from each machine with the `from` field being `alerts@our-domain.com`. We use G Suite to handle all emails (we have configured all `MX` records and the basic G Suite recommended `SPF`/`TXT` record).

Looking at [Google's instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) I found that:

1. Using SMTP relay is not acceptable since we needed to whitelist all IP addresses for new VMs and delete the IP addresses of deleted VMs.
2. Using Gmail SMTP server option is not acceptable since we needed to have a dedicated account (and pay for that) in order to login.
3. Using Restricted Gmail SMTP server we could have a limit problem, the messages are *marked* by G Suite Spam Filter and if we want to whitelist the VMs we are falling into a mix of problems of reason 1 and reason 2.

So my question is, what are the best practices to do this kind of email alerting? Do you guys add the IPs manually to G Suite's filters? Do you guys pay for an extra G Suite account?

Thanks in advance

Comment: authenticated relay service accounts are your friend...or I would use chatops > email...or a curl hook with sendgrid ..mandrill..etc

Comment: This is one of the things that Amazon SES is for.